# What is a user ID in Android <activity-alias>?

Tags: android, android-activity, userid

There is a concept in documentation called "User ID". Here is [the link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-alias-element.html#exported)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
By default, Android assigns each application its own unique user ID.
```

see this,,, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html#userid